# How to set highlighted image in Segmented Control in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi there I am using a segmented control in my app. I am also setting segmented controls setImage property to set an image for each segment of the control. I am not sure how to set an Image for its UIControlStateSelected state. I mean I would like to set an image for my segmented controls selected state. Please let me know how do I do that.

Thanks 
Sandy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to acheive you can try the following:

1. When you get a message from the control that a segment was clicked (UIControlEventValueChanged) change the image of the selected segment using the standard setImage:forSegmentAtIndex

OR

1. Set the momentary property of the control to true - this was cause your buttons not to be selected.
2. When you get the message that a segment was clicked replace it's image using the standard setImage:forSegmentAtIndex

Answer (score 0):

Get the subviews from the segmented control until you find the correct one, and then set the image on the selected segment explicitly.

Comment: If you do this, your app if very likely to crash on an OS update. It is also very likely to crash on the existing OS on iPhones with non-English regional settings (that happened to me for using a customized UISwitch)!

Comment: What would cause it to crash? setImage for selectedSegmentIndex or iterating through subviews. I have successfully used it with setImage: